# Cross domain callback error block in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url" ,
    jsonp: 'callback',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data, status, e) {},
    error: function() {
    }
```

In this code, the cross domain callback part `jsonp: 'callback'` is causing the error block code not to execute.

If there are any suggestions then let me know.

Also if the api url is changed, then which block should be executed? Success or error?

Comment: url is irrelevant when it comes to success or error blocks, its the request/response that drives that.

Comment: This is very generic piece of code. Please add some more info to clarify the question.